# How to print a string in diamond format in c#

Tags: c#, string, for-loop

If I have a word "start", I want to print like this  using **for loop**

```
   a
  tar
 start
  tar
   a
```

How to print string in c# when it is taking string with **odd number length** as input from the user eg: "START", "QUESTIONS"

Here is my code

```
string input;
for (int i = 1; i <= input.Length; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < (input.Length - 2); j++)
        Console.Write(" "); 
    for (int j = number; j < (number - 1); j--)
    {
        Console.Write(input[j]);
    }
    for (int k = number; k < i && k > 0; k++)
        Console.Write(input[k]); 
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Comment: i am getting half of the output

Comment: Then please add that code which gives half of the output

Comment: for (int i = 1; i <= input.Length; i++)
            {


                for (int j = 0; j < (input.Length - 2); j++)

                    Console.Write(" ");

                for (int j = number; j < (number - 1); j--)
                {
                    Console.Write(input[j]);
                }


                for (int k = number; k < i && k > 0; k++)

                    Console.Write(input[k]);


                Console.WriteLine(); <code>

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code, to use proper markup.

Comment: am new to stack overflow, iam unable to quote the code properly

Comment: @sanjayr are you always using and ODD value or length of character?

Comment: yes that is requirement

Comment: what is "number" in your code: "for (int j = number; j < (number - 1); j--)"

Comment: its not a number its a string eg:odd string (START)

Answer (score 3):

I doubt if this *Linq* routine will be accepted as a *homework solution*, however it could be useful for you for testing *your own code*:

```
   String source = "start";

   String result = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, Enumerable
     .Range(0, source.Length)
     .Select(index => source.Length - Math.Abs(index - source.Length / 2) * 2)
     .Where(length => length > 0) // for even size words, e.g. "star"
     .Select(length => source
       .Substring((source.Length - length) / 2, length)
       .PadLeft((source.Length - length) / 2 + length, ' ')));

   // Test
   //   a
   //  tar
   // start
   //  tar
   //   a
   Console.Write(result);
```

Comment: thanks for the reply but i need it in simple for loop

Answer (score 0):

If you *really* need a `for-loop` solution, you can do this

```
string input = "questions"; //for example
if (input.Length % 2 == 0)
    return; //as per given condition, only ODD length strings

var isReducing = false;
for (int i = 0, len = 1, startIndex = (input.Length - 1) / 2; i < input.Length; i++)
{
    var str = input.Substring(startIndex, len);
    Console.WriteLine(str.PadLeft(len + startIndex, ' '));
    if (len == input.Length)
        isReducing = true;
    startIndex = isReducing ? startIndex + 1 : startIndex - 1;
    len = isReducing ? len - 2 : len + 2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about 2 x for-loop :)

```
        string s = "0123456";
        int l = s.Length;
        int c = l / 2 + 1; //center

        for (int i = 0; i < c; i++)
            Console.WriteLine(s.Substring(c - i - 1, i * 2 + 1).PadLeft(c + i, ' '));
        for (int i = c - 2; i >= 0; i--)
            Console.WriteLine(s.Substring(c - i - 1, i * 2 + 1).PadLeft(c + i, ' '));
```